# Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource:Circular depends-on relationship between 'liquibase' & 'entityManagerFactory'

Tags: spring-boot, liquibase

I got this error after an upgrade to spring boot 2.6.3,
I tried rolling back to old different spring boot versions but that doesn't resolve the issue.
Spring boot Version : 2.6.3
Liquibase version 4.5.0

Liquibase configurations:
@Configuration
public class LiquibaseConfig {

```
 @Autowired
 private DataSource dataSource;
 

 @Bean
 public LiquibaseProperties liquibaseProperties() {
        return new LiquibaseProperties();
    }

 @DependsOn("entityManagerFactory")
  @Bean("liquibase")
  public SpringLiquibase liquibase() {
        LiquibaseProperties liquibaseProperties = liquibaseProperties();
        SpringLiquibase liquibase = new SpringLiquibase();
        liquibase.setChangeLog(liquibaseProperties.getChangeLog());
        liquibase.setContexts(liquibaseProperties.getContexts());
        liquibase.setDataSource(dataSource);
        liquibase.setDefaultSchema(liquibaseProperties.getDefaultSchema());
        liquibase.setDropFirst(liquibaseProperties.isDropFirst());
        liquibase.setShouldRun(true);
        liquibase.setLabels(liquibaseProperties.getLabels());
        liquibase.setChangeLogParameters(liquibaseProperties.getParameters());
        return liquibase;
    }
```

}

Error after starting up the project:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource
> [LiquibaseConfig.class]: Circular depends-on relationship between
> 'liquibase' and 'entityManagerFactory'    at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]     at
> org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154)
> ~[spring-context-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]   at
> org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908)
> ~[spring-context-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]   at
> org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
> ~[spring-context-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]   at
> org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145)
> ~[spring-boot-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]    at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:740)
> ~[spring-boot-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]    at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:415)
> ~[spring-boot-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]    at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
> ~[spring-boot-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]    at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1312)
> ~[spring-boot-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]    at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1301)
> ~[spring-boot-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]    at [package
> name].TestApplication.main(TestApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]

Comment: Why have you configured Liquibase to depend on the `entityManagerFactory` bean? Liquibase prepares the database and the entity manager factory accesses it so the dependency should be the other way around.

Comment: I use Hibernate to prepare the tables and relationships for me and  liquibase to  insert data into these tables, that's why I configured liquibase to run after the entity factory manager.

Comment: @MaxwellLangisi I am running into the same issue. In one of my environments but not on my local. Were you able to figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

While it isn't recommended to mix Hibernate and Liquibase's database initialization (you should really use Liquibase alone as it will make it easier to evolve your application's database schema), you can [opt in to that behaviour](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.6.x/reference/htmlsingle/#howto.data-initialization.dependencies.depends-on-initialization-detection) by setting `spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization` to `true`.

Answer (score 0):

Follow This :

1. Create New Class CustomSpringLiquibase.java

> ```
> public class CustomSpringLiquibase implements InitializingBean,
>     BeanNameAware, ResourceLoaderAware {
>
> private SpringLiquibase springLiquibase;
>
> public CustomSpringLiquibase(SpringLiquibase springLiquibase) {
>     this.springLiquibase = springLiquibase;
> }
>
>
> @Override
> public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
>
>     springLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet();
> }
>
> @Override
> public void setBeanName(String s) {
>     springLiquibase.setBeanName(s);
> }
>
> @Override
> public void setResourceLoader(ResourceLoader resourceLoader) {
>     springLiquibase.setResourceLoader(resourceLoader);
> }
> }
> ```

2. Edit your liquibase() method

> ```
> @Bean
> @DependsOn(value = "entityManagerFactory")
> public CustomSpringLiquibase liquibase() {
>     LiquibaseProperties liquibaseProperties = liquibaseProperties();
>     SpringLiquibase liquibase = new SpringLiquibase();
>     liquibase.setChangeLog(liquibaseProperties.getChangeLog());
>     liquibase.setContexts(liquibaseProperties.getContexts());
>     liquibase.setDataSource(getDataSource(liquibaseProperties));
>    liquibase.setDefaultSchema(liquibaseProperties.getDefaultSchema());
>     liquibase.setDropFirst(liquibaseProperties.isDropFirst());
>     liquibase.setShouldRun(true);
>     liquibase.setLabels(liquibaseProperties.getLabels());
> liquibase.setChangeLogParameters(liquibaseProperties.getParameters());
>     return new CustomSpringLiquibase(liquibase);
> }
> ```